# Can I free the radio spokesperson in Just cause 3?

Tags: just-cause-3

Every time I liberate a military outpost some unnamed character comes on the radio and announces that it was a "planned restructuring" of the outpost.

Later in the game he hints at being held in a cave and asks for help because he wants to get out. I thought I would be able to extract him at some point in the story missions, but that isn't the case.

Is it possible to find and save that person? If so, where can I find him?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to free him. Maybe in some DLC if we suggest it to the developers enough? Because I think it would be a fun bit of closure to that in-game joke.

Comment: rolling back edit (seriously though, the fact that he is "somewhere in a cave" is in no way a spoiler. If "being held against his will" is a spoiler, well im sorry, but "can I free him" already gives that one away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing a bit of browsing, trying to find someone else that potentially had rescued the radio spokesperson, it appears the answer is currently **no**.

---

This has come after some debate on the [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) [Just Cause board](https://www.reddit.com/r/JustCause/).

[On one page](https://www.reddit.com/r/JustCause/comments/3wpypv/is_it_possible_to_find_the_radio_guy/), several users confirm not being able to find him. One user confirms having this after destroying every antennae, transponder, and satellite dish. The page quickly gets distracted after confirmation that the spokesperson is, in fact, David Tenant.

[On another page](https://www.reddit.com/r/JustCause/comments/3vhwcm/propaganda_announcer/), users confirm the same thing, in more detail. One user, TehBanana_, adds some clarification.

> **[TehBanana_ posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/JustCause/comments/3vhwcm/propaganda_announcer/cxnxq5u):**
>   IMDb only lists him as a voice, other characters that have in game models aren't listed as voice only, so I don't think you can find him. It would be great if you could though.

---

As confirmed, on [the International Movies Database](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5127470/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast); the "Propaganda Minister" is listed as "voice only". As such, it is currently unlikely that he can be rescued, as there is no credit for the character model being in the game.

It appears odd that the minister would ask for rescue, without having any merit. It could be a joke, expected to be taken tongue in cheek; it could be eluding to future DLC content. But as such, it appears quite likely that the minister can not be rescued in the current game.

Comment: Thank you, I certainly hope we can do that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

After beating all the missions, the guy comes one to "dismiss rumors" of Di Rivello's assassination. He sort of freaks out and rejoices about do rivello's death instead. However, after the missions are complete, if you liberate a base, he will still come on and complain about being held captive.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may sound very sarcastic but in truth, completing the story gives an audio clip in which the newly saved propaganda minister is free and pokes fun at that fact among other things in which are spoilers